# Trouble with fonts in XeLaTeX in MacTeX 2016

Tags: fonts, xetex, mactex

Consider the code

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont [Ligatures=TeX]     {TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont [Scale=1.05]          {Latin Modern Math} 
\setmathfont [range=\mathbb]    {TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\def\csdef #1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\foo #1{\mathop{\mathcal{#1\kern 0pt }}\nolimits}
\def\Newfunction #1#2{\csdef{#1}{\mathop{\mathrm {\rm #2}\kern 0pt}\nolimits}}

\def\bor {\mathcal{B}\mathit{or}}
\Newfunction{Bor}{\mathcal{B}\mathit{or}}
\Newfunction{Imp}{\mathcal{I}\mkern -2mu \textit{mp}}

\parskip 5pt 

\begin{document} 
1) $\foo{B} + \foo{I}$ \par 
2) $\bor+\Bor$ \par
3) $\Imp$ \par
4) $\bigl((  \quad )\bigr)$ \par
\end{document}
```

With XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015), all is OK except the \big in item 4.

[image]

With XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016), the mathcal disappear in items 2, 3.
In item 4, the \big are too small and an extra space is added between parenthesis.

[image]

I still don't understand why item 1 is always correct...

Computer : MacMini late 2012 + Mac OSX El Capitan  10.11.5

Comment: Welcome! I get the output you show for 2016 also with 2015 and 2014. (Didn't test further back.)

Comment: It seems to be a bad bug in `unicode-math`; if the main font is set, `\mathrm{\mathcal{A}}` won't produce any character. The non `\big` delimiter problem is solved by issuing a final `\setmainfont[Scale=1.05,range=\int]{Latin Modern Math}` instruction, but the space after the `\bigl(` delimiter is another apparent bug (only in XeLaTeX).

Comment: I see that the mathcal{B} is gone, and it could be due to the changes in unicode math, but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by putting a \mathcal after a \rm in a \mathrm. The large spacing is related to the pagella font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It happens also with `\DeclareMathOperator{\FOO}{\mathcal{X}}` (with `amsmath`, of course), because, essentially, `\mathrm` is applied implicitly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get the space with XeLaTeX but not LuaLaTeX. And I get it with 2015 or 2016.

Comment: @egreg Interesting. Imho something for Will.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/356 and https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/357

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting the bugs in `unicode-math`, @egreg. The two issues have now been fixed with

- https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/3147086b80244df9e737e79f2f6808539bf47c69 and
- https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/0f245c2ec4c527397a67f3ff04aea8107a6cbe31 .

The relevant release is v0.8l from 2018-02-01.